# Changing from Prototype to JQuery leads to double POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

In chapter 12 of [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top) by Michael Hartl, there is a button on user's profile page you can flip to follow or unfollow him/her. (See figure 12.12 and 12.13)

I am using rvm 1.8.6 and Rails 3.1.1.

When I use Prototype, the behavior of clicking the button works correctly. 
In /sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

While clicking "follow", it does POST first and then GET to re-render the page. The logs are below.

```
Started POST "/relationships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-30 22:07:04 -0800
  Processing by RelationshipsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sVoNM/yyDmn0czvbza+dxzLsPW4mPNlGxAI1vKN7Ez4=", "relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"13"}, "commit"=>"Follow"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "13"]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 01 Dec 2011 06:07:04 UTC +00:00], ["followed_id", 13], ["follower_id", 1], ["updated_at", Thu, 01 Dec 2011 06:07:04 UTC +00:00]]
  Redirected to ht.p://localhost:3000/users/13
  Completed 302 Found in 52ms

Started GET "/users/13" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-30 22:07:04 -0800
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "13"]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Relationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = 1 AND "relationships"."followed_id" = 13 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = 1 AND "relationships"."followed_id" = 13 LIMIT 1
Rendered users/_unfollow.html.erb (6.9ms)
Rendered users/_follow_form.html.erb (54.5ms)
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = 13
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = 13
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."followed_id" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = 13
(0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = 13
Rendered shared/_stats.html.erb (4.2ms)
Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (67.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 100ms (Views: 83.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

But, after I followed the chapter 13 and switched to JQuery, the behavior of clicking the  follow button lead to exception and crashed the web server. 
After I modified /sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb to,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

it would do POST twice instead. And I guess the db unique violation crashed the Ruby. The logs are below.

```
Started POST "/relationships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-30 21:08:51 -0800
  Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sVoNM/yyDmn0czvbza+dxzLsPW4mPNlGxAI1vKN7Ez4=", "relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"19"}, "commit"=>"Follow"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "19"]]
  SQL (4.6ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 01 Dec 2011 05:08:51 UTC +00:00], ["followed_id", 19], ["follower_id", 1], ["updated_at", Thu, 01 Dec 2011 05:08:51 UTC +00:00]]
  Relationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = 1 AND "relationships"."followed_id" = 19 LIMIT 1
Rendered users/_unfollow.html.erb (3.7ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = 19
Rendered relationships/create.js.erb (7.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 13.7ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)


Started POST "/relationships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-30 21:08:51 -0800
  Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sVoNM/yyDmn0czvbza+dxzLsPW4mPNlGxAI1vKN7Ez4=", "relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"19"}, "commit"=>"Follow"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "19"]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 01 Dec 2011 05:08:51 UTC +00:00], ["followed_id", 19], ["follower_id", 1], ["updated_at", Thu, 01 Dec 2011 05:08:51 UTC +00:00]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms

SQLite3::ConstraintException (columns follower_id, followed_id are not unique):

Rendered /home/anson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered /home/anson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /home/anson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (4.2ms)
/home/anson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:84: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

-- control frame ----------
c:0044 p:---- s:0205 b:0205 l:000204 d:000204 CFUNC  :close
...
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Aborted
```

Can someone help please?

The codes are below.
app/views/users/_follow_form.html.erb

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
 <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

app/views/users/_follow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @user.id),
             :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Follow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

app/views/users/_unfollow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
             :html => { :method => :delete },
             :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Unfollow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/relationships/create.js.erb

```
$("follow_form").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("followers").update('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb

```
$("follow_form").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("followers").update('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

Comment: although i need to see the code, it is possible that the default form behavior (submit) is taking action as well as your js code. try adding an e.preventDefault in the beginning of the js code that handles the form submission.

Comment: I have added the codes. Can you pls instruct where exactly I can add e.preventDefault?

Comment: in the js event handler, function(e) { e.preventDefault();  ... }

Comment: If you're using Rails 3.1, you're not quite following the tutorial, which uses Rails 3.0. Using a version of Rails different from the one in the tutorial is likely to produce different results. I suggest using the exact gem versions used in the tutorial. If you're eager to use Rails 3.1, see Chapter 13. P.S. A new edition, using Rails 3.1 throughout, is currently in preparation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, including the server crashes, and managed to fix it like this:
(the requests had indeed been sent twice, probably because of the old scripts)
- delete basically all js files except application.js (which should be generated by rails new for rails 3.1)

```
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/controls.js
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/dragdrop.js
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/effects.js
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/prototype.js
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/rails.js
```

Additionally, create.js.erb needs to be adapted from prototype to query:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

and so does destroy.js.erb:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

after that, everything worked as before.

Answer (score 0):

Check your public folder for an Assets folder, with application.js in it. Not sure how I ended up with that, but that was causing ajax queries to be processed twice.